# ORACLE SQL | Modifying data in ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

following structure in a ORACLE table:

```
FILE_NAME
-----------
12345_l.tif
12345_m.tif
12345_r.tif
12345_x.tif
12345_y.tif
```

Need the following result:

```
First *_m*
Then *_l*
Then *_r*
Then * (everything else)
```

Trying with:

```
SELECT FILE_NAME FROM TABLE
WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE '12345%'
ORDER BY regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_m', '_1'),
         regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_l', '_2'),
         regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_r', '_3')
```

But this gives me a wrong result.

Anybody with a hint?

TIA Matt

Comment: are the file names really that similar? (like those numbers are not changing) if so, you could use SUBSTR and a case statement

Comment: The numbers in the result are always similar. I do filter this with a `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ORDER BY to order it by a numeric:

```
 ORDER BY regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_m', 1),
          regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_l', 2),
          regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_r', 3);
```

e.g.

```
WITH t
  AS (SELECT '12345_l.tif' AS file_name FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_m.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_r.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_x.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_y.tif' FROM dual)
SELECT file_name
  FROM t
 ORDER BY regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_m', 1),
          regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_l', 2),
          regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_r', 3);
```

Gives:

```
==============
12345_m.tif
12345_l.tif
12345_r.tif
12345_x.tif
12345_y.tif
```

Hope it helps...

Alternatively you could use:

```
 ORDER BY (CASE SUBSTR(file_name, INSTR(file_name, '_')+1, 1)
             WHEN 'm' THEN 1
             WHEN 'l' THEN 2
             WHEN 'r' THEN 3
             ELSE 4
            END) ASC;
```

E.G.:

```
WITH t
  AS (SELECT '12345_l.tif' AS file_name FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_y.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_r.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_x.tif' FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12345_m.tif' FROM dual)
SELECT file_name
  FROM t
 ORDER BY (CASE SUBSTR(file_name, INSTR(file_name, '_')+1, 1)
             WHEN 'm' THEN 1
             WHEN 'l' THEN 2
             WHEN 'r' THEN 3
             ELSE 4
            END) ASC;
```

Gives:

```
12345_m.tif
12345_l.tif
12345_r.tif
12345_x.tif
12345_y.tif
```

Comment: This was my solution:

`ORDER BY regexp_replace( regexp_replace (regexp_replace(FILE_NAME, '_r', 3), '_l', 2),'_m', 1) ASC;`

Comment: your second solution with `CASE` is much better, especially for extending. Thank you very much.