# SQL Order by using the values from two different columns

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a table NAME with the columns PART_TYPE and VALUE. Each type can have multiple types like FAMILY, GIVEN, PREFIX, etc.

What I would like to do is write SQL to get all the names but have them first ordered by a specific type then have them ordered alphabetically within that type.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM name
ORDER BY (
  CASE
    WHEN PART_TYPE = 'GIV'
    THEN VALUE
  END)
```

But I'm not sure how to include the other types as a primary order while keeping the VALUE as the secondary order. Adding another case statement will then just make VALUE the primary order.

I would like to keep this database independent but if need be, I would be willing to make it Oracle specific.

How can I do this? Also, a way of doing this with Hibernate Criteria would also be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I need the PART_TYPE to be ordered by a specific order as defined by me. In particular, it needs to be GIVEN then FAMILY.

So it should look like this:

```
GIVEN  A
GIVEN  B
GIVEN  C
FAMILY A
FAMILY B
```

The natural order by would have FAMILY first, not GIVEN.

Comment: `ORDER BY TYPE, VALUE` ?

Comment: @zerkms How to ensure the type is ordered by GIVEN then FAMILY?

Comment: This is a similar issue to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350330/oracle-sql-modifying-data-in-order-by/10350445#10350445

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am holding out to see if anyone has a Hibernate Criteria version of this. If one does not appear in a few hours, I'll still accept an answer.

Comment: `ORDER BY part_type DESC, value`?

Comment: @Dems There's more part types than that. The answers below solved this.

Comment: @AHungerArtist - Your comment on GarethD's answer states specifically `Fortunately there's only two types I have to worry about and it should be pretty consistent.`  But yes, if you have to re-order *multiple* entities, a table with a sort_order field is the way to go :)

Comment: @Dems I mean there's only two types I have to sort. There's more than two total types (as alluded to by the mention of PREFIX in the opening  sentence) but I only care about sorting on those two. Those other types come alphabetically before and after GIVEN AND FAMILY, so that why's that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most manageable way of resolving this is probably to have a table containing all your Types, and then a sort column within that. So you might have a table like:

```
TypeID      Name      SortOrder
1           FAMILY    2
2           GIVEN     1
3           PREFIX    3
```

Then you Can join this on to your query and use:

```
ORDER BY SortOrder, Value
```

You could just resolve this with a `CASE` expression

```
ORDER BY CASE Type
            WHEN 'GIVEN' THEN 1
            WHEN 'FAMILY' THEN 2
            WHEN 'PREFIX' THEN 3
            END,
            Value
```

But the more types you have the less manageable the case expression becomes.

Comment: Fortunately there's only two types I have to worry about and it should be pretty consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM name
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
        WHEN TYPE = 'GIVEN' THEN 1
        WHEN TYPE = 'FAMILY' THEN 2
        ELSE 3
     END,
  VALUE
```

This will order the result by a custom order on TYPE and VALUE as the secondary order.

Comment: But I need the type to be in a specific order, not by whatever order by defaults to. So, I need it to first sort by GIVEN, then FAMILy.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE TYPE
             WHEN 'GIVEN' THEN 0   
             WHEN 'FAMILY' THEN 1
             ELSE 2
         END,
         VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels a bit 'hacky' but it works

```
SELECT part_type,name
FROM (
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN part_type = 'Given' THEN 'A'
WHEN part_type = 'Family' THEN 'B'
END AS Sorthack,
part_type,
name
FROM NAME
) Sort

ORDER BY sorthack,name
```